# Find closest item in array of objects?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

When I have a reference to an item in an array, I'd like to find another item closest to it that matches a certain criteria.

For example, I have this array:

```
struct Person {
    var name = ""
    var age = ""
    var gender = ""
    var address = ""
}

let array = [Person(name:"ahmad",age:"22",gender:"male",address:"USA"),
             Person(name:"ahmad",age:"23",gender:"male",address:"KSA")]
```

Now let's say I have an object as:

```
let object = Person(name:"ahmad",age:"25",gender:"male",address:"USA")
```

based on that, I need to find the closest person to it on `array`, based on the values of all its properties.

As an example, based on my above code, the closest object in `array` to `object` is the first one because they have the same `name`, `gender` and `address` (3 matched properties), instead of the second one because there is only 2 matched properties.

Comment: "Closest item" is a very vague thing. You will probably have to make it yourself. Just make a loop on your array, checking for each properties of your items, incrementing a counter each time the property you check matches your criteria. Then, loop again on every counter to find the maximum counter. But again, "closest" is vague, so you will have to be more specific to deal with strings and things like that ..

Comment: @MartinR I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to define a function which measures the “closeness”
of two persons. Based on your example that could be

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: String
    let gender: String
    let address: String

    // Compute a number measuring the “closeness” to another person,
    // with smaller numbers meaning “closer”.
    // For example: the number of non-matching properties.
    func distance(to other: Person) -> Int {
        return (name == other.name ? 0 : 1)
            + (age == other.age ? 0 : 1)
            + (gender == other.gender ? 0 : 1)
            + (address == other.address ? 0 : 1)
    }
}
```

Then the closest person can be determined using `min(by:)`:

```
let object = Person(name:"ahmad", age:"25", gender:"male", address:"USA")
let closest = array.min(by: { $0.distance(to: object) < $1.distance(to: object) })!

print(closest) // Person(name: "ahmad", age: "22", gender: "male", address: "USA")
```

The above distance method is just an example, you have to adjust it
for your exact needs.

Comment: Maybe a more precise implementation should use an Euclidian distance rather than a 0/1 result

Comment: @CZ54: This returns the person which matches most properties of the given object, which is how I understand the question. Of course the metric can be modified for different needs.

Comment: I was just adding technic, of course your answer works

Comment: Damnit! Had to go to stand-up and left a half written answer. You got there first. Haha :D